# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://wallet.advcash.com/wsm/merchantWebService?wsdl' :

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am trying to using AdvCash API it's showing error on my server. I don't know about how to solve it. Please Help Me

API Details Link:  https://advcash.com/en/solutions/developers/

Check Image this error showing on my server.

my Server Link : https://skycallbd.com/tg/php-client/GetBalanceExample.php
[image]

my Code ::

```
<?php


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 100);
require_once("MerchantWebService.php");

$merchantWebService = new MerchantWebService();

$arg0 = new authDTO();
$arg0->apiName = "apiname";
$arg0->accountEmail = "account@gmail.com";
$arg0->authenticationToken = $merchantWebService->getAuthenticationToken("password");

$getBalances = new getBalances();
$getBalances->arg0 = $arg0;

try {
    $getBalancesResponse = $merchantWebService->getBalances($getBalances);

    echo print_r($getBalancesResponse, true)."<br/><br/>";
    echo print_r($getBalancesResponse->return, true)."<br/><br/>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "ERROR MESSAGE => " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

go to Library script (MerchantWebService.php ) And 2436 Line

Current libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
Change it to libxml_disable_entity_loader(true);